# Частичный вывод в файл

Tags: c++, файлы

Задача: находить среди всех строк строки с длиной >10 и <50 и записывать их в выходной файл в порядке возрастания.
Проблема: выводиться только одна строка
Вот код:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const char* filePath = "in.txt";
    struct Comp {
        bool operator()(const std::string& text1, const std::string& text2) const
        {
            return text1.size() < text2.size();
        }   
    };
    using Set = std::multiset<std::string, Comp>;
    Set setOfLines;
    std::ifstream fIn("in.txt");
    for (std::string line; std::getline(fIn, line);) 
    {
        if (line.size() > 10 && line.size() < 50) 
        {
            setOfLines.insert(line);
        }
    }
    for (const std::string& line : setOfLines) 
    {
        std::ofstream fOut("out.txt");
        fOut <<line;
    }
}
```

Во входном файле такие строки:

1. I love working
2. I love
3. I love working on the computer, I love Web Desgin
4. I love working on the computer, I love Web Desgin and etc.
5. Zdes bolshe desyati simvolov
6. Zdes bolshe pyatidesyati simvolov sto procentov da

Выводится только I love working on the computer, I love Web Desgin

В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите, что вы делаете:

```
for (const std::string& line : setOfLines) 
{
    std::ofstream fOut("out.txt");
    fOut <<line;
}
```

Для **каждой** строки вы открываете файл и **перезаписываете** его...

Понятно, что в файле остается одна, последняя строка...

```
std::ofstream fOut("out.txt");
for (const std::string& line : setOfLines) 
    fOut <<line << endl;
```